# Filter two data in the same Bucket Searchkick Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchkick

I have the next controller action:

```
  def index
    query                = params[:query].presence || "*"
    args                 = {}
    args[:name]          = params[:name]          if params[:name].present?
    args[:category_name] = params[:category_name] if params[:category_name].present?

    @items = Item.search query, where: args, aggs: { category_name: {} }
  end
```

I need to filter by name and by category (done)

But, also i need filter by two differents categories, for example:

```
category: "School", items: Notebook, Pencil, Pen, Board, etc

category: "Fruit", items: Banana, Pear, Grape, Apple, etc

category: "Vegetable", items: Broccoli, Carrots, Corn, Potatoes, etc
```

Then, the user selects "School" AND "Fruit" and the result should be a list of:

Notebook, Pencil, Pen, Board, etc

Banana, Pear, Grape, Apple, etc

Currently I have several different filters, I just put the "category" to show the problem, and I manage to filter results by all filters but only once each.

How can I handle the filters to allow two selections of the same filter?

Thanks!

Versions:

```
Rails 6.0.1

Ruby 2.6.5

Searchkick 4.1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by simply passing an array of values to `args[:category_name]`.

You could set up your search form so that your `params[:category_name]` returns an array of multiple selections and it should just work. Just to be safe, we can coerce the value into an array when necessary like so:

`args[:category_name] = Array(params[:category_name]) if params[:category_name].present?`